# Populate table items in a template document with C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, docx

I have a template document that has a header section displaying the details of a person and has a list section with a table of books.

All the data comes from a SQL Server database.

On my website, user clicks on the "Generate DOC" link that creates a filled document from a pre-defined/pre-designed template document.

I found many great tools that could be used to fill out a template document but my problem is with the tables. I couldn't find any tool that supports the filling of a pre-defined (templated) table.

I like [DOCX](http://docx.codeplex.com/) the most but I wasn't able to fill out the pre-defined table in the template document.

Are there any tools that would allow me to accomplish the above scenario? Does anybody have experience in this?

Some example code would be great!

Comment: Did you try doing it as a mailmerge?

Comment: Docmosis and JODReports can populate tables in templates.  Perhaps they have a C# api also?

Comment: @BugFinder what do you mean exactly?

Comment: A mailmerge uses a database or file to produce an output where the fields are replaced with data - this is exactly what you wanted.. to insert data at whatever points - you can even add If clauses to show sections if some field is this, and not if its not etc.. seems sensible to use a built in function if you can

Comment: This isn't really my issue. I can replace any single data in a template document easily. My problem is with filling out a table.
I will end up using simple HTML if I won't find any tool that support this behaviour.